# Can I enable character variants for fonts without enabling all other ligatures in VS Code?

Tags: visual-studio-code, fonts

I use [Fira Code](https://github.com/tonsky/FiraCode) as my font in vscode and i want to use the alternative "a" (`cv01`) and "g" (`cv02`) without enabling all other ligatures (like "=>" or "==").

Fira Code says you should put those into ["editor.fontLigatures"](https://github.com/tonsky/FiraCode/wiki/How-to-enable-stylistic-sets) as `"'cv01' 'cv02'"`, but that also enables all the other ligatures. is there a way to prevent this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For details on the syntax of the `editor.fontLigatures` setting when using strings instead of a boolean, see the `font-feature-settings` CSS property (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/font-feature-settings#syntax). You can use `'liga' 0` to disable common ligatures.

Comment: thanks a lot for the mdn docs, found out i can just turn off both `liga` and `calt` and that disables all other ligatures `"'cv01', 'cv02', 'liga' 0, 'calt' 0"`. ty